# How to use list and array to instantiate fields in a class?

Tags: php, arrays, list

I would like to instanciate every field of my PHP class at the same time. So far, I have tried using `list`. Here is my code below (which doesn't work). Any help would be gladly accepted.

```
class Test {
  private $x;
  private $y;
  private $z;

  public function Test() {
    $fields = array($this->x, $this->y, $this->z);
    // I need $fields to be an array here.
    list($fields) = array(1, 2, 3); // It would work if $fields wasn't an array.
    echo 'x = ' . $this->x . '<br />y = ' . $this->y . '<br />z = ' . $this->z;
  }
}

new Test();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list($this->x, $this->y, $this->z) = array(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot some information in the code. I need `$fields` to ba an array.

Comment: Why do you *need* it to be an array? Then you cannot use `list()`.

Comment: I do something else with the array here.

Comment: Well sorry, `list()` does not work with arrays, you have to list all your variables explicitly within `list()`. If that's not what you want, you need to assign the values in the traditional way `$this->x = 1; ...`.